# SQL Replace DATEDIFF filter with TOP 5

Tags: t-sql

I have a report that extracts data from a SQL Server database using the following script -

```
SELECT c.CaseID, h.[DisplayDate], h.Notes
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT CaseID 
FROM cr_Credit_Control 
) AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT CaseID, HistoryDate, CONVERT(VarChar, HistoryDate, 103) AS [DisplayDate], Notes
FROM History
WHERE Category = 'Payment Chased'
AND Active = 'True'
) AS h ON c.CaseID = h.CaseID
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day, h.HistoryDate, GETDATE()) <= 90
```

This provides a list of Cases each with History items within the last 90 days.
However, what I really want is to show the last 5 History items (per Case) regardless of when they were.  I'm guessing this requires the use of TOP and probably PARTITION but I'm struggling to make it work and would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.CaseID, h.[DisplayDate], h.Notes
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT CaseID 
    FROM cr_Credit_Control 
) AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CaseID, HistoryDate, CONVERT(VarChar, HistoryDate, 103) AS [DisplayDate], Notes
        ,Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY CaseID ORDER BY HistoryDate DESC) [Row]
    FROM History
    WHERE Category = 'Payment Chased'
    AND Active = 'True'
) AS h ON c.CaseID = h.CaseID
    AND h.[Row]<=5
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day, h.HistoryDate, GETDATE()) <= 90
```